# Não pode ser usado como função?

Tags: c, funções

Estou criando um programa que ordena alguns números de um vetor, sendo então uma ordenação bolha. Estou usando uma função chamada `trocar` para trocar os números de lugares quando um for maior que o outro, mas o compilador indica de que não posso utilizar esta função.

Meu código :

```
void trocar(int vetor[], int i) {
    int temp = vetor[0];
    vetor[0] = vetor[1];
    vetor[1] = temp;
}


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    int vetor[5],i,trocar,trocado = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(vetor[i] > vetor[i+1]) {
            trocar(vetor[i],vetor[i+1]);
            trocado = true;
        }
    }


}
```

Ele indica o seguinte erro :

> 'trocar' não pode ser usado como uma função

Como posso corrigir este erro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que você está recebendo é devido ao fato de você estar usando `trocar` como uma função.

Cada vez que você abre chaves `{}`, você define um novo escopo local, onde você pode redefinir os símbolos que existem em um escopo maior.

Nesse caso, o identificador `trocar` dentro do bloco está se referindo a uma variável local, portanto, você não pode usá-lo como uma função.
`trocar` no escopo *top-level* é uma função, mas dentro do bloco ele é ocultado (*shadowed*, no termo em inglês) pela definição da variável local com o mesmo nome.
Isso significa que você não pode chamar a função `trocar` dentro desse bloco (e quaisquer outros sub-blocos do mesmo).

Mais precisamente, você não pode acessar a função `trocar` pelo seu nome, mas você ainda pode chamá-la por um ponteiro para essa função acessível dentro desse escopo.

Isso deve servir como um incentivo para definir nomes significativos para suas funções e outros símbolos globais, uma vez que eles terão que coexistir no escopo *top-level* e correm o risco de serem ocultados por símbolos de alcance inferior.

Para resolver, renomeie sua variável local `trocar` ou renomeie sua função.

Comment: Obrigado novamente mercador por me ajudar, isto foi um erro que acabei deixando passar despercebido.